# RegEx to match with single occurrence of dash anywhere in [A-Z0-9]+ with total occurrence of 20 chars

Tags: regex

I couldn't figure out a regex to match with single occurrence of dash anywhere in [A-Z0-9]+ with max occurrence of 20 chars, so it's like - and [A-Z0-9]+ altogether max 20 chars.

This is the closest pattern I can get but didn't work

```
([A-Z0-9]{1,19}|\-{1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex, especially a single regex? These conditions are much easier to check separately.

For example, using Perl:

```perl
if (length($str) <= 20 && $str =~ /\A[A-Z0-9]*-[A-Z0-9]*\z/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a positive lookahead and assert the length to 1 - 20 chars:

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)[A-Z0-9]*-[A-Z0-9]*$
```

Depending on the tool or language, if you want to use different anchors than `^` and `$` to match the start and end of the string or line you might look at [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

For example:

```js
let pattern = /^(?=.{1,20}$)[A-Z0-9]*-[A-Z0-9]*$/;
[
  "AAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAA",
  "-",
  "A-A",
  "-A",
  "A-",
  "A",
  "AAAAAAAAAAA-AAAAAAAAA",
  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
].forEach(s => {
  if (pattern.test(s)) {
    console.log("Match: '" + s + "'  (Nr of chars: " + s.length + ")");
  } else {
    console.log("No match: '" + s + "'  (Nr of chars: " + s.length + ")");
  }
});
```